# Read ECONNRESET - Meteor

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, ubuntu, meteor

I am suddenly getting this error & there is no way I am able to trace the issue, my server keeps crashing again & again, and I haven't done any changes in months for sure.

```
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Anyone facing this issue or have solution to the crash?

Comment: Did you check the server vitals like RAM, CPU and Storage? Did you try to deploy your application else where and it still crashes? How about checking some APM metrics?

Comment: You need to provide more details. Help us help you.

Comment: Yes i deployment on different server and there it works fine.

Comment: How can I provide you APM metrics?

Comment: Monti APM or Meteor APM

Comment: >Yes i deployment on different server and there it works fine.
You said you made no changes on your code but you may have made changes on your server. Please revise any changes however minute.

Comment: Let me check that

Comment: That server literally wasn't touched in months. Yes we did used apps connected to that. But nothing else

Comment: What version of Meteor is your application running on? Have you tried bumping or downgrading it?

Comment: Although I using Meteor 1.9, could that be the reason, will upgrading to latest meteor version help?

Comment: Give it a try you never know but don't make huge leaps. Increase the version to next immediate one and see if it helps.

Comment: "That server literally wasn't touched in months" -- in that case my first guess would be a full disk. Have you already checked that? Could you also post more context for the error above? When does that happen?

Comment: I have free diskspace & this crash is totally random & I have no insights about that, thats the thing worrying me

Comment: With These `process.nextTick` in the Stack I would search for async Code that is not wrapped in the Meteor Environment and thus can Crash the Servers. All "sinks" and npm packages with unwrapped async calls should be checked

Comment: @Jankapunkt Can you explain this? May be with some example code? I am not getting your point here

Comment: ECONNRESET is a networking error that indicates the driver received an RST packet when it was expecting data.  If that RST packet originated at the distant server, I would expect that server to log something.  You may need to do a network dump on both sides to try to find the source of the reset.

Comment: @joe that's pretty strange. How can i check those logs?

Comment: Have you been abe to locate the issue? In that case, can you explain how you resolved it?  We are currently facing the same issue.